# How to force anim folder to be discovered in Xamarin Android project?

Tags: android, animation, xamarin

In my applciation I want to add simple slide in / slide out animations when switching fragments. I've read about easy and straightforward solution: adding 'anim' folder under 'Resources' folder and putting there our animations in .xml files. But after I did that 'anim' is not present in the Resources object when I try to address it like `Resources.anim.slide_in`. It underscores the anim word red and gives me a compile-time error:

```
CS0117 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'anim'.
```

I've tried cleaning, rebuilding the project, closing it and opening again, renaming folder to "Anim", "animator", "Animator", tried `Resource.animator`, `Resource.Anim`, `Resource.Animator`, changed xml contents to different animations... whatever I could think of I tried! And after enormous amount of time spent googling I'm begging you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I repeated your steps:

1) created an folder under `Resources` named `anim`

2) Access the resources with `Resource.Animation.`

And it worked. Even so there is no `anim` folder I am able to type and find `Resource.Animation`. But in this case no animation can be found.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer would have saved my day if I hadn't found Animation property myself finally (I should have examined Resources file in the beginning, stupid me). But it's so strange that it is Animation property and not anim because in all sources I found it was .anim property and never Animation!